# Node js db2 module

Tags: node.js, db2

I'm using that code

```
var ibmdb = require('ibm_db')

function executeSql(sql)
{
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    ibmdb.open("DRIVER={DB2};DATABASE=SITRAN;...",(err,conn) => {
      if (err) reject(Error(err))
      conn.query(sql,(err,rows) => {
        if (err) reject(Error(err))
        console.log('length:',rows.length)
        conn.close(() => { console.log('done'); resolve(rows); })
        })
      })
  })
}

executeSql(sql)
.then((result) => { console.log('result:',result.length) })
```

The db2 part is working, it gives `1045` rows but the code is working strangely

```
length: 0
length: 1045
done
result: 0
```

I don't understand why `length` is displayed twice, one with 0 and one with 1045.  And also why the `resolve(rows)` seems not working.

Answer (score 0):

`conn.query()` is an asynchronous function which might explain the double `console.log()` behavior. As far as the weird behavior with `resolve()`, try `resolve(rows.fetchAllSync())` instead.